# LinqPad timeout connecting to remote SQL Server

Tags: linqpad

I'm trying to connect my hosting providers SQL Server with LinqPad. It works fine using SSMS, but times out when trying to fetch the database list. I am successfully authenticated (via the test)... [ and if i change the credentials, it fails]...

Is there a way to extend the timeout??

Thanks - Kevin

Answer (score 2):

The timeout for fetching schema information in LINQPad is 4 minutes, so something is going badly wrong if it times out! On the dialog, did you click 'Display all databases in TreeView' or did you connect to specific database?

Comment: Hey Joe... neither option works: display all in treeview times out at 30 seconds [I timed it this time]; and selecting 'Specify new or existing database' also times out after 30 seconds when you try to populate the dropdown list. 
I got it to work by selecting "Specify new or existing database" and then just typing in my db name. There are a LOT of db's on this server, so maybe it's timing out just trying to get the list of names. They show up 'instantly' in SSMS - so I'm not sure what's different... and the timeout is definitely 30 seconds.

Comment: I see - it's timing out when querying the list of databases, rather than populating the schema. What happens when you execute sp_MShasdbaccess on that server? Does it execute quickly or take forever?

Comment: Hi Joe - I just ran sp_MShasdbaccess - and it completed in a whopping 5 minutes and 27 seconds. I re-confirmed that it times out in 30 sec from the connection settings form. Not sure what's going on - but I'm able to work around it by typing in my db name. Thanks for your help and for a great learning tool.

Comment: Hi Joe, I am also having this issue. The remote server, our QA server has a lot of databases (150+) if I connect to a specific one it's fine, but I cannot get the list, it just time's out. SSMM displays them almost instantly though.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that our DBA mentioned is to set the database property "Auto Close" to false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188124.aspx

We did this on our development database server and it worked fine for linqpad with a few hundred databases.